# Meteor, race condition / intergrity of sequence

Tags: meteor

Potential issue (general):

User A enters a chat message (using browser/client A), the message gets added to his view immediately, and it also gets sent to the server. The server sends it to user/client B for update of his view. But in the meantime user B enters a chat message, it gets added to his view immediately - there now is message B as last message in user B's chat history and message A as last message in user A's chat history. This would be an issue in many use cases, considering for example the case where people compete in a quiz and it's relevant who posted the correct answer first.

How does this get handled in Meteor?

Potential Solution (for web apps where integrity of the sequence is crucial):

Don't have immediate client view updates.

Just send the piece of data (which also is an update request) to the server who adds it to the central model and distributes it to all clients (incl the client of the user who created the piece of data).

Each client updates its model and view, then sends a short "I processed the update request I got" to the server.

The server waits for the last such signal (ignoring users who disconnected) [1], and then is ready for the next piece of data (the next update request). If there are items in the queue, process those first.

This way, whichever data piece reaches the server first wins (and wins on all clients), and the data piece that reached the server a bit later will be processed after the first one has been reflected in each client.

(The fact that the view update in the creator's client happens a bit later (because it the data goes through the server first) is not a huge problem I guess.)

[1] (ensure that accidental disconnects are always handled)

Tobi

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, what happens in meteor will be this (obviously depending on the order of execution):

1. User A creates message `A_c` on client
2. User A creates message `A_s` on server (this happens automatically)
3. User B creates message `B_c` on client
4. `A_s` is distributed to both User A and User B, replacing `A_c` for A, and `B_c` for B.
5. User B creates message `B_s` on server
6. `B_s` is distributed to both users.

So what will probably happen (depending on whether 4 or 5 happens first), is that B will see a little bit of flickering while her message is shunted down to below A's. Possibly a better solution can be reached by being more specific in your use of `Meteor.method`s (rather than just using the implicit ones created by the collection for you).

IMHO the occasional weird flickering (this is an edge case I suppose, depending on latency) is a much better solution than having a lag in the view update for the creator in *every case*.